# How to share data between controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have to create a service that shares an array but I can't figure out how to show one of the arrays in the view.

```js
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module('ShoppingListCheckOff', [])
 .controller('ToBuyController', ToBuyController)
 .controller('AlreadyBoughtController', AlreadyBoughtController)
 .service('ShoppingListCheckOffService', ShoppingListCheckOffService);

 ToBuyController.$inject = ['ShoppingListCheckOffService'];
 function ToBuyController(ShoppingListCheckOffService) {
  var ToBuyCtrl = this;

  ToBuyCtrl.buyItems = ShoppingListCheckOffService.getBuyItems();

  ToBuyCtrl.CheckItem = function () {
   ShoppingListCheckOffService.CheckItem(ToBuyCtrl.itemName, ToBuyCtrl.quantity, ToBuyCtrl.index);
  };

  ToBuyCtrl.setBougthItems = function () {
   ShoppingListCheckOffService.setBougthItems(ToBuyCtrl.itemName, ToBuyCtrl.quantity);
  }
 };

 AlreadyBoughtController.$inject = ['ShoppingListCheckOffService'];
 function AlreadyBoughtController(ShoppingListCheckOffService) {
  var AlreadyBoughtCtrl = this;

  AlreadyBoughtCtrl.bougthItems = ShoppingListCheckOffService.getBougthItems();
 };

 function ShoppingListCheckOffService() {
  var service = this;

  var buyItems = [
   {name: 'Coockies', quantity: '10 bags'},
   {name: 'Cereal', quantity: '4 boxes'},
   {name: 'Orange juice', quantity: '4 botles'},
   {name: 'Soda drinks', quantity: '2 botles'},
   {name: 'Cerael bars', quantity: '10 bags'},
   {name: 'Milk', quantity: '4 botles'}
  ];

  var bougthItems = [];

  service.CheckItem = function (itemName, quantity, index) {
   var item = {
    name: itemName,
    quantity: quantity
   };
   buyItems.splice(index, 1);
   bougthItems.push(item);
  };

  service.getBuyItems = function () {
   return buyItems;
  };

  service.setBougthItems = function (itemName, quantity) {
   var item = {
    name: itemName,
    quantity: quantity
   };
   bougthItems.push(item);
  };

  service.getBougthItems = function () {
   return bougthItems;
  };
 };
})();

In the app.js i have created an "ShoppingListCheckService" service that shares the array of "ToBuy" and "AlreadyBought".
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ShoppingListCheckOff">
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List Check Off</h1>

  <div class="row">

    <!-- To Buy List -->
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="ToBuyController as ToBuyCtrl">
     <h2>To Buy:</h2>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="buyItem in ToBuyCtrl.buyItems">{{buyItem.quantity}} - {{buyItem.name}}<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ToBuyCtrl.CheckItem(buyItem.quantity, buyItem.name, $index) && ToBuyCtrl.setBougthItems(ToBuyCtrl.itemName, ToBuyCtrl.quantity);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Bought</button></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="emptyMessage" ng-if="ToBuyCtrl.buyItems.length === 0">Everything is bought!</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Already Bought List -->
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="AlreadyBoughtController as AlreadyBoughtCtrl">
     <h2>Already Bought:</h2>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="boughtItem in AlreadyBoughtCtrl.boughtItems">{{boughtItem.quantity}} - {{boughtItem.name}}</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="emptyMessage" ng-if="AlreadyBoughtCtrl.boughtItems.lenght === 0">Nothing bought yet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

In the HTML i manage to show the first array, but i cant figure out how to move an item from the "ToBuy" array to the "AlreadyBought" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because of two reasons.

1. You were not catching itemName and quantity in ToBuyCtrl.CheckItem() method.(Was easy to find)
2. Spelling mistake in your ng-repeat (boughtItem in AlreadyBoughtCtrl.boug**ht**Items) where as you were assigning the item to boug**th**Items. (Took a lot of time to find)

Also, you dont need ToBuyCtrl.setBougthItems() method since you are pushing data to boughtItems array in your service. If you are planning to remove it, be sure to remove it from markup as well.

```
ToBuyCtrl.CheckItem = function (itemName, quantity, index) {
            ShoppingListCheckOffService.CheckItem(itemName, quantity, index);
        };
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Champana/h49num1t/)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a service method for that which, in some way, identifies the element in ToBuy array, removes it, and then adds it to the AlreadyBought array. For example, say I know the index of the element to move, I could do something like this:

```
service.moveToBought = function(index) {
    service.bought.push(service.buy[index]);
    service.buy.splice(index, 1);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78a5tv7d/)